# Sequelize where condition for multiple tables not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

While building Sequelize query unable to filter data from two tables with two different where conditions. Here I am adding some code...

**Models:**

```
//Task model
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Task = sequelize.define("Task", {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
    start : DataTypes.DATE,
    finish : DataTypes.DATE,
    status : DataTypes.STRING(1),
    }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Task.belongsTo(models.User, {
          onDelete: "CASCADE",
          foreignKey: {
            allowNull: true
          }
        });

        Task.hasOne(models.Evaluation);
        Task.hasMany(models.Clarification);
      }
    }
  });
  return Task;
};
//Evaluation model
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Evaluation = sequelize.define("Evaluation", {
    agent_id : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    agent_name: DataTypes.STRING(100),
    status: DataTypes.STRING(100),

    }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Evaluation.belongsTo(models.Task, {
          onDelete: "CASCADE",
          foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false
          }
        });
        Evaluation.hasMany(models.Clarification);
      }
    }
  });
  return Evaluation;
};
//Clarification model
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Clarification = sequelize.define("Clarification", {
    result : DataTypes.TEXT,
    status : DataTypes.STRING(100),
    comment : DataTypes.TEXT
    }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Clarification.belongsTo(models.Task, {
          onDelete: "CASCADE",
          foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false
          }
        });
        Clarification.belongsTo(models.Evaluation, {
          onDelete: "CASCADE",
          foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return Clarification;
};
```

I just added required code not exactly same.

Actually Using:

```
var filterobj = {
    where: {
            "UserId": { $ne: "NULL" }
        },
    include: [{
        model: models.Evaluation,
        attributes: ["id", "status","agent_name"],
        where: {
            "status": { $ne: "created" }
        },
        include: [{
            model: models.EvalForm,
            attributes: ["id", "name","LobId"],
            include: [{
                model: models.Lob,
                attributes: ["id", "ClientId"]
            },
            {
                model: models.FormDetails,
                attributes: ["version", "status"]
            }
            ]
        }, {
            model: models.Clarification,
            attributes: ["id", "status"]
        }],
        required: true
    },{
        model: models.User,
        attributes: ["name"]
    }]
};
models.Task.findAll(filterobj).then(function (tasklist) {
    // Doing some stuff for specific format
    return res.send(tasklist);
}).catch(function (err) {
    return res.send({ "error": { "code": 5000, "message": err.message } });
});
```

**Response:**

```
[
{
        "id": 760,
        "type": "clarification",
        "start": "2017-07-12T14:30:52.000Z",
        "finish": "2017-07-13T05:41:56.000Z",
        "status": "A",
        "UserId": 854,
        "Evaluation": {
            "id": 760,
            "status": "completed",
            "agent_name": "TestAgent1",
            "EvalForm": {
                "id": 5000008,
                "name": "MobiPostpaid1",
                "LobId": 26,
                "Lob": {
                    "id": 26,
                    "ClientId": 1
                },
                "FormDetails": [
                    {
                        "version": 1,
                        "status": "A"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Clarifications": [
                {
                    "id": 70,
                    "status": "raised"
                },
                {
                    "id": 71,
                    "status": "esclate"
                }
            ]
        },
        "User": {
            "name": "pooja.s"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 761,
        "type": "clarification",
        "start": "2017-07-12T14:30:52.000Z",
        "finish": "2017-07-12T14:35:30.000Z",
        "status": "A",
        "UserId": 854,
        "Evaluation": {
            "id": 761,
            "status": "assigned",
            "agent_name": "TestAgent1",
            "EvalForm": {
                "id": 5000008,
                "name": "MobiPostpaid1",
                "LobId": 26,
                "Lob": {
                    "id": 26,
                    "ClientId": 1
                },
                "FormDetails": [
                    {
                        "version": 1,
                        "status": "A"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Clarifications": []
        },
        "User": {
            "name": "pooja.s"
        }
    }
]
```

**Expected Code(Not working)**

```
var filterobj = {
    where: {
            "UserId": { $ne: "NULL" }
        },
    include: [{
        model: models.Evaluation,
        where: {
            "status": { $in: ["assigned","completed"] }
        },
        attributes: ["id", "status","agent_name"],
        include: [{
            model: models.EvalForm,
            attributes: ["id", "name","LobId"],
            include: [{
                model: models.Lob,
                attributes: ["id", "ClientId"]
            },
            {
                model: models.FormDetails,
                attributes: ["version", "status"]
            }
            ]
        }, {
            model: models.Clarification,
            attributes: ["id", "status"]
        }],
        required: true
    },{
        model: models.User,
        attributes: ["name"]
    }, {
        model: models.Clarification,
        where: {
            "status": { $in: ["raised"] }
        }
        attributes: ["id", "status"]
    }]
};

models.Task.findAll(filterobj).then(function (tasklist) {
    // Doing some stuff for specific format
    return res.send(tasklist);
}).catch(function (err) {
    return res.send({ "error": { "code": 5000, "message": err.message } });
});
```

**Expected Response:**

```
[
{
        "id": 760,
        "type": "clarification",
        "start": "2017-07-12T14:30:52.000Z",
        "finish": "2017-07-13T05:41:56.000Z",
        "status": "A",
        "UserId": 854,
        "Evaluation": {
            "id": 760,
            "status": "completed",
            "agent_name": "TestAgent1",
            "EvalForm": {
                "id": 5000008,
                "name": "MobiPostpaid1",
                "LobId": 26,
                "Lob": {
                    "id": 26,
                    "ClientId": 1
                },
                "FormDetails": [
                    {
                        "version": 1,
                        "status": "A"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Clarifications": [
                {
                    "id": 70,
                    "status": "raised"
                },
                {
                    "id": 71,
                    "status": "esclate"
                }
            ]
        },
        "User": {
            "name": "pooja.s"
        },
        "Clarifications": [
            {
                "id": 70,
                "status": "raised"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 761,
        "type": "clarification",
        "start": "2017-07-12T14:30:52.000Z",
        "finish": "2017-07-12T14:35:30.000Z",
        "status": "A",
        "UserId": 854,
        "Evaluation": {
            "id": 761,
            "status": "assigned",
            "agent_name": "TestAgent1",
            "EvalForm": {
                "id": 5000008,
                "name": "MobiPostpaid1",
                "LobId": 26,
                "Lob": {
                    "id": 26,
                    "ClientId": 1
                },
                "FormDetails": [
                    {
                        "version": 1,
                        "status": "A"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Clarifications": []
        },
        "User": {
            "name": "pooja.s"
        },
        "Clarifications": []
    }
]
```

I can include **Clarification** table inside **Task** and **Evaluation** tables I have that association. The problem with **where** condition. It is pulling all the records. I am expecting data from **Clarification** table with status **raised**. And from **Evaluation** table status with assigned and completed. Some where I saw code using **OR** operator.

```
A.findAll({
    where: {
        $or: [
            {'$B.userId$' : 100},
            {'$C.userId$' : 100}
        ]
    },
    include: [{
        model: B,
        required: false

    }, {
        model: C,
        required: false
    }]
});
```

But this is not working for me.

Comment: you have two where keys inside include for evaluation model

Comment: Also Instead of posting I am getting all data
Can u post the query you expected vs what you got

Comment: @Shivam, I have three models which are Task, Evaluation and Clarification. I want to include Evaluation and Clarifications for each Task(You can understand relation between them in the models above). Each Evaluation and Clarification have different statues. For each Task we have Evaluation, But Clarifications are optional. If we have Clarifications we need Clarifications also. So for each Task definitely we will get Evaluation, if Clarifications exist we need to include Clarifications also.

Comment: I have to include Evaluation and Clarifications based on statues, So I am trying to put two where conditions but not working as I am expected. For time being I am just pulling all the data and filtering based on statues using javascript. The above code is expected one, but not actually using. From the above code I just removed where conditions and not including   Clarifications inside Task. Just including Clarifications inside Evaluation and using js for status filter.

Comment: @Shivam, Please look for the changes that will helps to understand issue.

Comment: Reiterating to undestand it better, You need tasks along with those of its Evaluations which have a particular status (status of Evaluation and not Task) and Similarly those Classifications which have a particular status

Comment: @Shivam, What you understood is correct. I have statues for Evaluations and Clarifications, not for Tasks. I want to include Evaluations and Clarifications inside Tasks with different status conditions.